# Implementing a custom system call in Kernel Version 3.16.x

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel

There are many resources available on the net (also on Youtube) on how to implement a custom System Call before making the kernel. They are mostly simple ones (like printing hello world/adding two numbers). I want to implement a more complex one (printing task_struct for a process using its PID) which is not possible to get correct in a single go. Do I have to run "make modules_install" again and again to see the result of my changes in my code for the call? 
Considering I can't dry run my code using a conventional GCC compiler since I am including linux/xyz.h and other header files and commands like (printk()) that are only possible in kernel mode. 
I am new to C and kernel hacking, please excuse me if I am asking something that is very obvious.

Code that I want to run:
http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2012/07/module-to-find-task-from-its-pid.html

Comment: As system call is part of the kernel core and not a part of a module, rerunning `make modules_install` after changing it is not required. However, you still need to run `make install` for update the kernel image.

Comment: So do I have to make the kernel again

Comment: As you modify the kernel's code, you need to rebuild it again. Note, that `make` is quite intelligent tool: it will rebuild only those objects files, which sources has been modified since the last build.

Comment: I tried using make, I stopped the kernel building when it started making the drivers again, is there some special flag that I need to pass?

Comment: I found the solution, which I am writing here for future reference.
Try installing ccache (https://ccache.dev/), and while making use the command 'sudo ccache make' instead of 'sudo make'. The first compilation would be of normal time since cache is created. Subsequent compilations didn't take longer than 2 minutes on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Make only rebuilds changed source code files. You don't need an external library like ccache.dev . Try doing make -j 8 .